# How to redirect user to requested page even after attempting wrong login -PHP

Tags: php, redirect

For suppose i have requested a page before login i:e

www.website.com/Product/135

on click buy i am redirected to login page

**Header.php**

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['last_req_url'] = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
```

**This is login form**

```
    <form action="" method="post">
    <input placeholder="Email or Mobile :" name="user_email2" value="<?php echo $_POST['user_email2']?>" type="text" tabindex="6" required />
    <input placeholder="Password" type="password" name="password" tabindex="6" required />
    <input type="hidden" name="last_req_url" value="<? echo $_SESSION['last_req_url']; ?>" />
    <input type="submit" value="Sign In" name="log_btn" tabindex="6" id="register-submit">
    </form>
```

Even if i make some wrong login attempts i want to redirect my user to

www.website.com/Product/135

After last successful login

**Login.php**

```
if(isset($_POST['log_btn']))

{

/**************LAST VISTED PAGE REDIRECT***********************/

            //var_dump($_POST);

            if(isset($_POST['last_req_url'])){ 
                $url = $_POST['last_req_url']; // holds url for last page visited.
                //echo '-----------';
                redirect_page($url);
            }


}
```

Comment: I would append the product url to the link containing the login page. `www.website.com/login.php?redirectTo=URL-Validated`

Comment: Could you please expain a bit more accurate what you want. because if i use this code, and just change <? $_SESSION['last_req_url']; ?> to <?php $_SESSION['last_req_url']; ?>, i'm getting redirected no matter what. Well, maybe your server supports <?, and it's just mine that doesn't.